# asp.nep mvc: setting values from current httpcontext to constant variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

Hi i am currently working on asp.net application, and i have a class in which i need to check whether a specfic cookie exists in the current context. 
So far it works fine, however I was told ny someone that it would be best to have the boolean thats checks, as a constant, in this manner:

```
const bool labelcookieexists = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("MyCookie");
```

However intellisense starts complaining when i do this, and says that the expression in not const.

Can someone explain whether or not things from the current httpcontext can be declared as constant. I dont really understand why it cant myself

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your left side variable is constant, but right side expression is runtime constant and it should be compile time constant.

your right hand expression will return values at runtime, so you can not assign it to constant. it required values at compile time, that is the reason of your error.

you can use readonly for it, which support runtime constant.

```
private readonly static bool labelcookieexists = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("MyCookie");
```

Answer (score 0):

A **constant** is a value that will forever remain the same for the lifetime of the application. And because you are reading the value from the cookie, even if its once, it means this value is not a constant... Use `readonly`